# How to reference other project with ANT?

Tags: java, deployment, ant, jenkins

I'm creating my build.xml and it works fine to generate the .war file.
But there's a small problem: I have got three projects: A, B and C. The project A (that I'll deploy with ANT) uses the classes of project B and C.

Then I just need a way so that when A is compiled it includes the project B and C as libs...

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `path` with a `pathelement` for each jar file you need to include, and then include it as a classpath reference in your compile step.

For instance, if I define `dependenciesClassPath` like this:

```
<path id="dependenciesClassPath">
    <pathelement path="${some.lib.dir}/ProjectB.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="${some.lib.dir}/ProjectC.jar"/>
</path>
```

then I can include it in my compile target like so:

```
<javac destdir="${targetDir}/classes" source="1.7" target="1.7" debug="true">
    <src refid="baseSourcePath"/>
    <classpath refid="dependenciesClassPath"/>
</javac>
```